# Pde problem with Neumann BC's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

Let $U \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set with smooth boundary $\partial U$. Consider the Neumann boundary problem 
$$-\Delta u +u=f, \quad  \left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\right|_{\partial U}=0.$$

(a) Define the notion of weak solution.

(b) Prove existence of weak solutions.

(c) Assume $f \in C^{\infty}(\bar U)$ and the weak solution is smooth. Show that $u$ satisfies the Neumann boundary condition.

(a): Considering Green's identity and boundary condition i conclude that
$u \in H^1(U)$ is weak solution of our problem if $\int_U (Dv Du + vu) dx = \int_U fv dx$ for any $v\in H^1(U)$.

(b): Using standard norm on $H^1(U)$ and defining bounded linear functional on $H^{1*}(U)$
$$ F_f(v) = \int_U fv dx $$ 
i can show the existence and uniqueness of weak solution $u \in H^1(U)$ via Riesz representation theorem.

Part (c) is causing me problems. I don't even understand the question and i have no idea how to do it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to incorporate the boundary conditions in the definition of the notion of solution, as is usually done when dealing with dirichlet b.cs? (sorry if the comment is useless, I don't know the answer but this was my first idea...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right on (a) and (b).
For (c), you assume that $u\in C^\infty(\bar U)$ satisfies the weak formulation. You have to show $\partial u/\partial n = 0$ on the boundary. This can be done as usual: testing with a smooth function and integrating by parts.

Comment: Thanks but i don't really get it. I used the boundary condition to arrive at weak formulation. Should i reformulate my definition for weak solution?

Comment: Yes, you have integrated by parts and used the boundary condition. Now, you go the other way round. Then, you arrive at $\int_\Omega -\Delta u \, \phi \, dx = \int_\Gamma \partial u/\partial n \, \phi \, d s$ (maybe the signs are not correct). Using your PDE, the first term is zero...

Comment: i just use Green's identity and i arrive at: $\int_U (D v D u + v \Delta u)dx = \int_{\partial U}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}dS $. How did you arrive at yours and i also don't see why the first term (left hand side) is zero :(

Comment: Ups, I forgot a $u \, \phi$ in my comment. You can use the fact that $u$ solves your weak formulation, hence $\int Dv\,Du + v \, u = 0$. Then you use $-\Delta u + u = 0$ (in the sense of distributions), which follows also from your weak formulation.

Comment: Sorry but i am still confused...wouldn't my weak formulation then be $\int_U (Dv Du + vu) dx - \int_{\partial U} v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}dS = \int_U fv dx$ for any $v\in$ some space (i don't know which space).

Comment: No, in order to pose the weak formulation, you use the boundary condition and drop the boundary integral term.

Comment: But i have to prove that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$ and therefore i cannot used it to pose a weak formulation. I am getting even more confused.

Comment: No, the weak formulation for your problem is $\int_U Dv \, Du + v \, u - f \, v \, dx = 0$ for all $v \in H^1(U)$.

Comment: Multiplying equation by a test function $v \in H^1(U)$ and integrate over $U$: $ \int_U v(-\Delta u +u)dx = \int_U fv dx.$
Green's identity: $\int_U (D v D u + v \Delta u)dx = \int_{\partial U}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}dS$. Then $ \int_U v(-\Delta u) dx = \int_U Dv Du dx -\int_{\partial U}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}dS$
Weak formulation: $u \in H^1(U)$ is weak solution of our problem if $\int_U (Dv Du + vu) dx -\int_{\partial U}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}dS= \int_U fv dx$ for any $v\in H^1(U)$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much but i really don't see how to conclude $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0$

Comment: Your weak formulation contains $\partial u/\partial n$ on the boundary. This is not defined for $u \in H^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: So then i assume $\int_U (DvDu + vu - fv)dx=0$...Only now i use Green's identity and then conclude $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$ ? It's looks weird going that way. where do i use smothness of $u$ and that $f \in C^{\infty}(\bar U)$.

Comment: You need the smoothness of $u$ in order to show that $-\Delta u + u = f$ holds pointwise in $U$. Actually, the smothness of $f$ follows.

Comment: I did this. Would you say it's ok? Assuming $u$ satisfies weak solution, i.e. $\int_U (Dv Du + vu) dx = \int_U fv dx$. From Green's identity we know $\int_U D v D u dx= - \int_U v \Delta u dx + \int_{\partial U}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}dS$. Hence, $ \int_U (-v \Delta u + vu) dx + \int_{\partial U}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}dS = \int_U fv dx $. Since $u$ is smooth, $-\Delta u +u = f$ holds pointwise in $U$. Therefore: $ \int_{\partial U}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}dS=0$
which holds for any test function $v \in H^1(U)$(or is $v$ somewhere else?). Then $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$

Comment: You can assume, e.g., $v \in C^\infty(\bar U)$ or something like that. Then it looks fine.

Comment: i added a bounty on my newest question. If you are interested in helping, you can check it out.